# Can you upgrade rundeck straight from 3.0.22 to 3.2.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 "bionic" with OpenJDK on GCP?

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, rundeck

Failed with this so I did a `systemctl stop rundeckd` followed by an `apt-get --purge remove rundeck` followed by restoring three files in `/etc/rundeckd` (profile, framework.properties, rundeck-config.properties which I had backed up) and restarted with `systemctl start rundeckd` and things are working again. Now I don't want to upgrade rundeck again due to the above experience. **Can one not go directly from 3.0.22 to 3.2.1 rundeck?**

The working packages are:

`openjdk-8-jdk-headless/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 8u232-b09-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]`

`openjdk-8-jre-headless/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 8u232-b09-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]`

`rundeck/now 3.0.22.20190512-1.201905130100 all [installed,local]`

The console log of the attempt to startup 3.2.1 using `systemctl start rundeckd`

```
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

[2020-01-16 22:53:37.436]  WARN AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext --- [           main] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsInterceptorMappedInterceptor': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6f12b637' of type [org.grails.plugins.web.interceptors.GrailsInterceptorHandlerInterceptorAdapter] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6f12b637': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setInterceptors' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controllerBaseInterceptor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uiPluginService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'frameworkService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizationService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configStorageService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rundeckConfigStorageTreeFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'storagePluginProviderService' while setting bean property 'storagePluginProviderService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storagePluginProviderService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rundeckFramework' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'frameworkFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'frameworkFilesystem' while setting bean property 'frameworkFilesystem'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'frameworkFilesystem': Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.common.FilesystemFramework]: Factory method 'createFilesystemFramework' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: project base directory could not be created. /var/rundeck/projects
[2020-01-16 22:53:37.538] ERROR SpringApplication --- [           main] Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsInterceptorMappedInterceptor': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6f12b637' of type [org.grails.plugins.web.interceptors.GrailsInterceptorHandlerInterceptorAdapter] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6f12b637': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setInterceptors' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controllerBaseInterceptor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uiPluginService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'frameworkService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizationService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configStorageService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rundeckConfigStorageTreeFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'storagePluginProviderService' while setting bean property 'storagePluginProviderService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storagePluginProviderService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rundeckFramework' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'frameworkFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'frameworkFilesystem' while setting bean property 'frameworkFilesystem'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'frameworkFilesystem': Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.common.FilesystemFramework]: Factory method 'createFilesystemFramework' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: project base directory could not be created. /var/rundeck/projects
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:84)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:393)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:380)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
    at rundeckapp.Application.main(Application.groovy:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsInterceptorMappedInterceptor': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6f12b637' of type [org.grails.plugins.web.interceptors.GrailsInterceptorHandlerInterceptorAdapter] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6f12b637': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setInterceptors' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controllerBaseInterceptor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uiPluginService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'frameworkService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizationService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configStorageService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rundeckConfigStorageTreeFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'storagePluginProviderService' while setting bean property 'storagePluginProviderService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storagePluginProviderService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rundeckFramework' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'frameworkFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'frameworkFilesystem' while setting bean property 'frameworkFilesystem'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'frameworkFilesystem': Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.common.FilesystemFramework]: Factory method 'createFilesystemFramework' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: project base directory could not be created. /var/rundeck/projects
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:289)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.detectMappedInterceptors(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:247)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1622)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `framework.projects.dir` in the default install of Rundeck 3.2 in the config file `framework.properties` has changed to:

```
framework.projects.dir=/var/lib/rundeck/projects
```

Please follow the instructions: [Upgrading to Rundeck 3.2](https://docs.rundeck.com/3.2.1/upgrading/upgrading-to-rundeck-3.2.html#upgrading-from-rundeck-3-0-using-debian-rpm-packaging)

Comment: Thanks - that took care of it. Running 3.2.1 now.